# react component function on button does not run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im new to react and have run into a problem with a button not running a function when clicking it.  Its a simple console log function but it doesnt work.  The same problem has popped into another component where it doesnt console log data it fetched from the server.

When rendering the component the button does not run the function attached to it.  However when I make a small change in the Card component in VScode and save it, then all of a sudden the button works as intended.

I cannot figure out why it is not running.

sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-haslett-hpyxg?file=/src/index.js

app.js

```
const components={
    overview: <Overview />,
    product: <ModifyProduct />,
    addProduct: <AddProducts />
  }

  const [component, setcomponent] = useState(components.overview)

  

  return (
    <div style={container}>
      <div style={sidebarStyle}>
          <button style ={buttonStyle} onClick={() => setcomponent(components.overview)}>Home</button>
          <button style ={buttonStyle} onClick={() => setcomponent(components.addProduct)}>Add Product</button>
          <button style ={buttonStyle} onClick={() => setcomponent(components.product)}>Manage Product</button>
      </div>
      <div style={mainWindowStyle}>
        {component}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Results.js

```
useEffect(() => {
      listItems.length === 0 ? setdisplay(<div>Search for something</div>) : setdisplay(<Results block={listItems} />)
      
    }, [listItems]);
    
    const sendFormData = () => {
      fetch(
        'http://localhost:5000/admin/manageproduct/search',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                  product
                }
            ),
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
          }
      )
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      //.then(data2 => setListItems(data2))
    }

        const clearInputs = () => {
            setProductNameInput('')
            setNumberInStockInput('')
            setProductIDInput('')
            setCategoryInput('')
        }

    const product = {
      productName: productNameInput,
      numberInStock: numberInStockInput,
      productID: productIDInput,
      category: categoryInput
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <div style={inputStyleContainer}>
            <input style={inputStyle} value={product.productName} type="text" placeholder="Product Name" onChange={event => setProductNameInput(event.target.value)} />

            <input  style={inputStyle} value={product.productIDInput} type="text" placeholder="ProductID" onChange={event => setProductIDInput(event.target.value)}/>

            <input  style={inputStyle} value={product.numberInStockInput} type="number" min="0"placeholder="number in stock" onChange={event => setNumberInStockInput(event.target.value)} />

            <input  style={inputStyle} value={product.categoryInput} type="text" placeholder="Category" onChange={event => setCategoryInput(event.target.value)}/>
          </div>
            <br />
          <div style={buttonContainer}>
            <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => sendFormData()}>
              Search
            </button>
            <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => clearInputs()}>
              Clear
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            {
              display
            }
          </div> 
        </div>
            
    )
}
```

Card.js

```
const click = () => {
    console.log('cleecked')
  }

  return (
    <div style={cardStyleContainer}>
      
      <img onMouseEnter={() => mouseOver()} onMouseLeave={() => mouseExit()} style={imageSize} src='https://picsum.photos/1920/1080' alt="pic"/>
      <div>
        {category}
      </div> 
      <div>
        {productName}
      </div>
      <div>
        {numberInStock}
      </div>
      <div>
        {category}
      </div>
      <div>
        R{price}
      </div>
      <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => click()}>This button</button>
      
    </div>
      )
}
```

Comment: Storing component instances in state is an antipattern. Instead, store a name or something in state, and conditionally render the component.

Comment: For example, if the const `components` is within the function body, it will create a new instance of those 3 components every time `app` re-renders. Meaning it will lose any local state.